# Firebase image uploading to storage Android error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

There,
I have been following a YouTube video for Firebase making a simple blog app , where user can upload a image with one title & some description . So when I am clicking the submit button my progress bar is keep looping for infinite time. I am not getting any solution for this. Please help me.

Two Activities are there one is `PostActivity.java` and another is `MainActivity.Java`

`PostActivity.java`:-

```
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton img_btn_add_photo;
    private EditText et_post_title,et_post_description;
    private Button btn_post_submit;

    private Uri mImageUri = null;

    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private StorageReference mStorage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        et_post_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_post_title);
        et_post_description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_post_description);

        btn_post_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_post_submit);

        img_btn_add_photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_btn_add_photo);
        img_btn_add_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });


        btn_post_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submitToDB();
            }
        });

    }

    private void submitToDB() {


        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Submitting Post...");
        mProgressDialog.show();

        final String title = et_post_title.getText().toString().trim();
        final String descr = et_post_description.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(descr) && mImageUri != null){

            StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            filePath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            mImageUri = data.getData();
            img_btn_add_photo.setImageURI(mImageUri);

        }

    }
}
```

`Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PostActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

in `MainAcitivity.java` only one add button is there in menu. so I haven't uploaded it here. please help.

Comment: What says the log? any warning from firebase?

Comment: no warning sir.. i followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0ScnHJi8WY&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt&index=19

Comment: I think you have to try to read carefully the Log... Maybe firebase is not allowing you register your image

Comment: if this is the reason.. how to check it... sir my logcat..is showing some error  but i am not getting ... how to solve ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ,You've enabled in firebase storage to write file without authentication

```
    service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```